# Invalid alignment value for assembly .align 32 instruction

Tags: macos, assembly, gnu-assembler

.align 32 or .align 64 generate an error in gas assembly for apple with clang compiler. ( Invalid alignment value )
.align 16 is ok.

How can i align properly with avx2 and avx512 simd instructions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, `.align` is a synonym for `.p2align` (not `.balign`), so aligning by 2^64 is a bit much. :P

To avoid ambiguity, just use `.p2align 6` or `.balign 64`.

Comment: Yes.Thank you. Seems for gas apple syntax.

Comment: @Stephane: It's not apple-specific, that's how GAS for x86 works on other platforms.  So Apple Clang treats `.align` the same as GAS does, unsuprisingly.

Comment: To avoid problems i'll use .balign because it seems .align is whether a power or a number depending on target (architecture / compiler).

Comment: @Stephane: right, it's different on different architectures.  I was answering for x86.  It's definitely better to be explicit and use p2align or balign, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Correction, in GAS for x86 Linux, `.align` is definitely `.balign`.  Even more reason to never use `.align`, always one of the non-ambiguous ones.